# Getting day, month, year from the string format "DD-MM-YYYY"

Tags: php

I have a date in string format `DD-MM-YYYY`.

```
date_string = "08-01-2008";
```

I would like to extract the day, month, year information from `date_string` such that;

```
day="08";
month="01";
year="2008";
```

How can this be done in php?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$string = "08-01-2208";

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("d-m-Y", $string);
echo $date->format("d"); //day
echo $date->format("m"); //month
echo $date->format("Y"); //year
```

Comment: Can i use instead of  `-` (dash)  a `/` (slash) ?
Something like this: `$string = "08/01/2208";...` and `...createFromFormat("d/m/Y", $string);`

Answer (score 3):

try `explode()`

```
$datearr = explode('-', $date_string);
echo $datearr[0]; //day
echo $datearr[1]; // month
echo $datearr[2]; // year
```

or `date()`

```
$day = date('d', strtotime($date_string));
$month = date('m', strtotime($date_string));
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date_string));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `strtotime`. Try with the following.

```
$date=strtotime($date_string);
$month=date("F",$date);
$year=date("Y",$date);
$day=date("d",$date);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if strtotime can parse a Dutch date-format

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$date_string = "08-01-2008";
$splitDate = explode('-', $date_string);
$day = $splitDate[0];
$month = $splitDate[1];
$year = $splitDate[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$date_string = "08-01-2008";
list($day, $month, $year) = explode("-",$date_string);
```

Comment: -1 for using explode to parse dates.

Comment: @sectus - It depends on the context. For example, if he gets the dates from a flat file and just needs to separate day, month, year as he explained, using explode is nice and quick. If he needs fancier stuff like timezones than it's better to use DateTime.